# eCommerce system with simple order form

Tags: ubercart, commerce

I need a food order system to embed in my drupal 7 website.
I added the screen shot of the design here:

[image]

I don't want a full eCommerce system.User can select items and the items will be listed in the order list.They can edit the no of items from remove items form the order list.After send an order the order will be stored in db and the site admin can view it on the admin part.From he can process it manually.There is no payment system for it and this is only to track the order and deliver it manually.

Can you please suggest me better way to accomplish it.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to do something similar to this in the past, where the website client wanted users to be able to mark items as favorites, and then email that list of favorites to the client for pricing and further information. Rather than building a whole e-commerce setup, I used [webform](https://drupal.org/project/webform) and [webform view](https://drupal.org/project/webform_view).

Here is the basic setup:

1. Create 'food item' content type or whatever will be most appropriate for each of your food items
2. Create a view that displays the food item nodes.
3. Create a webform that collects user information (such as contact information when submitting an order
4. Embed your food item view in that webform using the webform view module.

When people then fill out the form, they can select which 'food item' nodes they, want, the quantity, or any other custommizations that you can create using the webform (special requests, delivery method, anything you'd like). They will also enter in any relevant contact information and send it to you as a standard webform.

[Webform view has great documentation](http://drupalcode.org/project/webform_view.git/blob_plain/refs/heads/7.x-1.x:/help/index.html). It can be a little confusing the first time you try to use it though, so I suggest you follow exactly the documentation in webform view to get an idea for how this module works, and then modify it accordingly for your food item view.

I liked this method too as then the food items are their own content type, so if you do want to do something with e-commerce for real in the future, you should be able to migrate those nodes to products for something like drupal commerce.

Comment: kbrinner thanks for the valuable reply.
I want to see all these user submission in the admin part.So admin can enter into it and process the order. I hope we can do this by the web-form .Let me try this.Could you please give me the link that you had done before?

Comment: It's still under development so it's not available to the public. I will post again once the website is generally available. And yes, because you are using webform you can see all of the user submissions as you would normally for any webform submission.

Comment: The website is live - http://baldwinartgroup.com/searchable-artwork-all - add some items to your bag and then view your bag to see the form below the items you added to your bag. I'd also appreciate it if you accepted my answer :)

Comment: thank you for the reply.i've checked your website this is working good. I've done my site in another way and please have a look. http://www.kababone.com/kabab1-menu